# Salt with using Mcrypt

Tags: php, salt

I'm trying to generate salt using Mcrypt's `mcrypt_create_iv()`, but it doesn't seems to work and I'm getting errors.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$salt= substr(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM))(mt_rand()),0,22);

echo $salt;
?>
```

Comment: Always post any relevant errors or traceback.

Comment: What errors, exactly?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in /root/phptest/blowfish.php on line 4

Comment: You have problems with parentheses. Always do syntax checking before running. I recommend using an IDE (e.g. NetBeans) with syntax checking capability.

Comment: Are you sure that this extension is enabled [Mcript on PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$salt = substr( mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM), mt_rand( 0, 22 ) );
```

you have some syntax errors

Comment: not working in getting this error Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_create_iv() in /root/phptest/blowfish.php on line 4

Comment: sorry not working ether getting this error Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_create_iv() in /root/phptest/blowfish.php on line 4

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work, you use `mcrypt_create_iv()` to get random bytes, but those cannot be used for hashing with BCrypt. The problem is, that mcrypt_create_iv returns binary data, while BCrypt expects a salt with characters of a given alphabet. You would have to encode your salt to this alphabet: `./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`. The function `mt_rand()` is of no use here.

PHP 5.5 will have it's own functions password_hash() and password_verify() ready, to simplify generating BCrypt password hashes. I strongly recommend to use this excellent api, or it's [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) for earlier PHP versions. The usage is very straightforward:

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```